# css property definition

Tags: html, css

I have a css class for a table definition like the following

```
.tabborder
{
    border:           1px solid black;
    border-collapse:  collapse;
}
```

And then I want all the `th` and `td` elements that are nested within the  element that has the class="tabborder" to do the following

```
.tabborder th, td
{
    border:           1px solid black;
    border-spacing:   0;
}
```

Having `th, td`  wouldnt work while just `th` or `td` works the way I want it to.

Is there a workaround for that. I know that writing seprate definitions like below works
But is there an efficient way to do this

```
 .tabborder th
{
    border:           1px solid black;
    border-spacing:   0;
}

 .tabborder td
{
    border:           1px solid black;
    border-spacing:   0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comma is used to [group separate selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping).

> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all
>   elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list. (A
>   comma is U+002C.) For example, in CSS when several selectors share the
>   same declarations, they may be grouped into a comma-separated list.
>   White space may appear before and/or after the comma.

Although `.tabborder` is specified in the first selector, it is *not* implied in any subsequent selector.

```
.tabborder th,
.tabborder td /* you must specify .tabborder for each selector */
{
    border:           1px solid black;
    border-spacing:   0;
}
```

[**edit**] Alternatively, since a `tr` can directly contain only `td` and `th` elements ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr-content-model)), you may combine the [child `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) and [universal `*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) selectors ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDz9u/)):

```
.tabborder tr > *
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;   
    padding: 3px 6px;
}​
```